Variance-Covariance Matrix of the OLS Estimator vs OLS Estimator of the Variance-Covariance Matrix
Suppose a model $y = X\beta + e$ that is unbiased and consistent but has some sort of heteroscedasticity or autocorrelation, thus, $E(ee'|X)=\delta^2 \Omega$.
In the exercise that I'm currently trying to solve, they ask for the most appropriate variance-covariance matrix for the Ordinary Least Estimator for the model but also for the  OLS estimator of the variance-covariance matrix. My question is, what is the difference between Variance-Covariance Matrix of the OLS Estimator vs OLS Estimator of the Variance-Covariance Matrix?

It will help you to know that a model is neither inherently unbiased or consistent, but estimators can be.  Perhaps maintaining a keener awareness of the distinction between a model and an estimator will help you.

You have to distinguish between the variance-covariance matrix (ort short just the covariance matrix) of the error terms, i.e., $E[ee'|X]=\sigma^2 \Omega$ in your example, and the variance-covariance matrix of the OLS estimator, i.e., $Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1} X' \delta^2 \Omega X (X'X)^{-1}$. In the case of no autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity in the error terms, this reduces to $E[ee'|X]=\sigma^2 I$ and $Var(\hat{\beta})=\delta^2 (X'X)^{-1}$.

@Louki That's a great answer and well worth elevating from a comment to an actual post.  I would recommend, though, clarifying what you mean by "$\delta$" compared to "$\sigma$" and I would also be a little concerned about how estimates of $\sigma^2$ play a role in OLS.

Thanks, I can write a post later! And, I am sorry, it should be $E[ee'|X] = \delta^2 \Omega$ and $E[ee'|X] = \delta^2 I$. (I'm too used writing $\sigma^2$, my bad.) And indeed, I should add details on the estimates of $\delta^2$.

$\newcommand{Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$ Let's start with your second point. The difference between the variance-covariance matrix of the OLS estimator and the OLS estimator of the variance-covariance matrix is the following. (In the following, I will abbreviate the variance-covariance to just covariance matrix.)
Given that we have the OLS estimator of the given regression model, $\hat{\beta}$, the covariance matrix of the OLS estimator is given by
$$\Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1}X'\delta^2 \Omega X(X'X)^{-1},$$
where we can observe that in the case of uncorrelated and homoskedastic errors that this reduces to the following (well-known) formula: $\Var(\hat{\beta})=\delta^2 (X'X)^{-1}$. In the case of uncorrelated and homoskedastic errors we have that $\Omega=I$ and the rest follows (note in the above formula that $\delta^2$ is a scalar). Furthermore, note that $\delta^2$ here does not refer to an estimator but rather to a parameter in the population.
A different animal is the OLS estimator of the covariance matrix. Let's start with the strong OLS assumption, which usually consists of assuming no correlation of the error terms and homoskedasticity. In this case, the OLS estimator of the covariance matrix is given by
$$\hat{\delta}^2 = \frac{e'e}{T-2}.$$
If we deviate from these assumptions, things get more involved. So, let's look quickly at the structure of the covariance matrix. If we have heteroskedastic and correlated errors, then $\Var(e) = E[ee'\mid X]=\delta^2 \Omega$, where $\delta^2$ just refers to the common volatility across observations while $\Omega$ is matrix modeling the potential heteroskedasticity and correlation structure. Therefore, to find an estimator for $\delta^2$ and $\Omega$ is a challenge and involves assumption. In case of autocorrelation, you can use an (F)GLS estimator and assume a serially correlated errors, e.g., with $e_t = \rho e_{t-1} + u_t, |\rho|<1$. Another possibility is to employ an appropriate HAC estimator for its covariance.
Once you have an estimator for the covariance matrix, you can also estimate the covariance matrix of the OLS estimator, i.e.,
$$\widehat{\Var(\hat{\beta})} = (X'X)^{-1}X'\hat{\delta^2}\hat{\Omega} X(X'X)^{-1}.$$

Hi Louki: That was very nicely explained but maybe put a hat on the $\Omega$ immediately  above so that it's clear that it's an estimate and not the actual matrix. Come to think of it, $\delta^2$ should probably get a hat too !!!!!

@mlofton It comes down to whether one is referring to the var-cov matrix or to an estimate of it ;-).

I think that it should not have a hat, because it is not an estimate. Quite generally, $E[ee‘|X] = \delta^2 \Omega$ could be anything. Only after you assume something (e.g., HAC, AR(1) of the errors, deterministic heteroskedasticity, …) we should put a hat on it. This is important since knowing or not knowing the exact structure has implications about the (un)biasedness and consistency of the OLS estimator.

I just noticed: in the last equation, there should indeed be a hat on the $\delta^2$ and $\Omega$; have edited.

Hi Louki: I was referring to the last equation with "immediately above". I don't think you need a hat on the whole Var on the LHS because $Var(\hat{\beta})$ is already clear. But it's your nice answer so just a suggestion. Great answer.

Thanks! I think either way it‘s hopefully clear.

Hi Louki: it's EXTREMELY clear. I was just thinking that, since it's such a nice answer, why have a little thing at the end. All the best.
